# reticulateを使ってRstudio上でPythonを書こうとすると，R Session Abortedになってしまいます。

Tags: python, r

お世話になります。初めて質問させていただきます。
RstudioでPythonを使いたいのですが，毎回強制終了になってしまいます。

いくつか対処を試みたのですが，自分では解決できなかったので教えていただきたいです。
これまでに行ったことを記載していますが，必要な情報があれば，ご指摘ください。
恐れ入りますが，よろしくお願いいたします。

● 実施したいこと
Rstudio上でPythonを使いたいです。

● 実行環境
R: *R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)*
Rstudio:*Version 1.4.904*
Python: *3.6.12*
（他にも必要な情報があれば，ご指摘ください）

● 実行したこととエラー

実行したコードは以下です。

```
library(reticulate)
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "C:/Users/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe")
repl_ptyhon()
```

**repl_python()を実行すると，R Session Aborbedとなり，強制終了してしまいます。コンソールに実行結果は示されるのですが，この時点でR Session Aborbedとなってしまいテキストのコピーができないため，画像添付にて失礼します**

[image]

● 要因仮説（主に2つ）

1つ目は，Teminalでpythonと入力すると，以下のエラーが出てきます。

> Warning:
> This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
> not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
> please see https://conda.io/activation

> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

conda環境がactivateされていないというエラーのようだが，Anaconda Prompto（anaconda3）を見るとactivateされていると思われる。

> (r-reticulate) PS C:\Users\ (myname)>

2つ目は，以下を実行するとエラーが出てきます。
r-reticulateが仮想空間ではない，というエラーのようですが，これが意味するところがわかりませんでした。

```
install_tensorflow(method = "virtualenv")
```

> virtualenv_install(envname = envname, packages = packages, ...) でエラー:
> 'C:/Users/ (myname) /AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate' exists but is not a virtual environment

Comment: [rstudio/reticulate: R Interface to Python](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate) を眺めてみますと、"The use_virtualenv() and use_condaenv() functions enable you to specify versions of Python in virtual or Conda environments, for example: ..." などと書かれています。さらに [Python Version Configuration • reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html) を見ると、`use_condaenv()` を実行する必要がありそうです。

Comment: @metropolis さん，ご返信誠にありがとうございます！use_conda()にパスを実行してみたのですが，repl_python()を実行した際にクラッシュしてしまうエラーは改善されませんでした。コンソール上には画像のような表示が出ますので，恐らく実行自体はされているのかなと思うのですが，，，PCのスペックなども関係ありますかね。

Comment: Anaconda の仮想環境の名前が "r-reticulate" になっている様ですので、`use_condaenv("r-reticulate")` を試して見てください。

Comment: @metropolis さん，ありがとうございます。
`use_condaenv("r-reticulate")`として実行してみましたが，やはりR Session Aborbedという画面が出てきてRstudioが強制終了してしまいます。

今試してみたのは，以下のコードです。
`library(reticulate)`
`use_condaenv("r-reticulate", required = TRUE)  `
`reticulate::py_config()  `
`repl_python()`

Comment: @metropolis さん，色々とありがとうございました！
あの後，Rstudioのバージョンを1.4から1.3に変更したところ，うまくいきました。一方，改めて1.4に戻すとやはりうまくいきませんでした。なので，バージョンの問題なのかな？と思っています。

Comment: なるほど、r-reticulate が Rstudio 1.4 には未対応なのかもしれませんね。。

Comment: もう解決したようですが, おそらく R Studio のバージョンが原因とは断言できないと思います (1.4 からは reticulate のサポートも強化されていますし): 他の条件は違いますが, 私の環境では RStudio 1.4.x でも動作しています. (RStudio 1.4.1071 preview, Python: 3.8.2 (pyenv), reticulate: 1.18, OS: Ubuntu 18.04).  (どちらにせよ現在はまだ preview 版ですが) 私も別のバージョンで原因不明のクラッシュが頻発したことがありましたが `repl_python()` 以外では動作することが多いです. その時は `matplotlib` を 3.2 に戻したら動作するようになったため, この手の原因の特定は難しいと思います.

Comment: ありがとうございます！仰る通り、Rstudioは1.4でpythonのサポート強化されてるはず…と思っていたので不思議でした。そして、1.4でも動いているのですね。ちなみに、matplotlibのバージョンが原因であることは、どのようにして気づかれたのでしょうか？

Comment: matplotlib の件は, reticulate を経由しないと再現できないバグだったので, 根気よく環境やコードを切り詰め最小の再現条件を探していたら見つけられました.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

【**更新**】 2021/6/1 にリリースされた RStudio 1.4.1717 以降のバージョンを使用すればこの問題は解消されると思われます.

R-wakalang でもやり取りがありましたが, 公共性のためオープンなこちらの方でも書いておきます. 既に [issue #8285](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8285) で言及されている問題と関係があるようで, (1) Windows 10 を英語以外の言語設定で使用し, かつ (2) RStudio 1.4台 (<= 1.4.1103) 使用時に発生する問題のようです. よって, 以下のような回避方法があります.

(1) Windows の言語設定を English にする
(2) Windows 以外の OS にする (仮想環境でも可能かは未検証)
(3) RStudio 1.3 台に戻す, または RStudio を使わずに実行する
(4) `repl_python()` を使わない, つまり Python REPL を起動しない方法で使う(R 上で Python モジュールをインポートして使う, Rmd の knit, など)

**更新**
issue [#8549](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8549) によると RStudio daily build 1.4.1533 以降でこの問題が発生しなくなっているようです. 私も自身の Windows マシンで確認しました.

https://dailies.rstudio.com/rstudio/oss/windows/

Comment: ありがとうございます。RstudioでPythonを使いたいと思っていましたが，今のところWindowsを日本語にしたままRstudio1.4では難しそうですね。今後解決されることを願ってもう少し待つことにしています。

Comment: RStudio daily build 1.4.1533 以降でこの問題が発生しなくなっているらしいです  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8549#issuecomment-770553293

Answer (score -1):

私もWin10環境でクラッシュしました（RStudioのEnvironmentをRからPythonに切り替えるだけで）が、Rを英語のセッションにすることで回避できました。

C:/Users/ユーザー名/Documents/.Renviron

がなければ作り、

LANG=C （とかLANG=en_US.UTF-8とか）

としてみてください（RStudio 1.4.1106＋R 4.0.5）。